# Multiple upload Laravel file-manager

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Buenas estoy intentando hacer una galería de imagenes, utilizando Laravel file-manager. He puesto un script para que me ponga todas las imagenes que cargo una a una, pero todo el rato me la sobreescribe. La idea es ir cogiendo a través de file-manager, una a una las fotos que quiero añadir al input y luego cargarlas en una bd.

```
<div class="col-8">
    <div class="form-group input-group">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <a id="galeria" data-input="thumbnail3" data-preview="holder3" class="lfm2 btn btnUpload">
           <i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i> Subir galeria
          </a>
          </span>
          <input id="thumbnail3" class="form-control formNuevo" type="text" name="galeria[]">
         </div>
       </div>

 <div class="col-3"></div>
     <div class="col-8">
       <div id="other_images_container">
          <img id="holder3" style="margin-top:15px;margin-bottom:20px;max-height:100px;margin-right:15px;margin-left:15px;">
       </div>
  </div>
```

**El Script**

```
var y = 2;

        $('#galeria').click(function () {
            $('[class*="lfm2"]').each(function() {
                $(this).filemanager('image', {prefix: route_prefix});
            });

            var input = '<input id="thumbnail3'+y+'" class="form-control" type="hidden" name="galeria[]">';
            var image = '<img id="holder3'+y+'" style="margin-top:15px;margin-bottom:20px;max-height:100px;margin-right:15px;margin-left:15px;">';

            $(this).append(input);
            $('#other_images_container').append(image);
            $('.lfm2').attr('data-input', 'thumbnail3'+y).attr('data-preview', 'holder3'+y);
            y++;
        });
```

**El paquete que estoy utilizando, aunque mi versión es la 1.8**

https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-filemanager

**Edición para mostrar que paso cuando hago click en `#galeria`**

Nada más entrar en el formulario de edición me carga este input:

```
<input id="thumbnail3" class="form-control formNuevo" type="hidden" name="galeria[]">
```

Si hago clic en `#galeria` me crea esto:

```
<input id="thumbnail32" class="form-control" type="hidden" name="galeria[]">
```

Cuando añado la foto me sustituye la linea de arriba por esta:

```
<input id="thumbnail32" class="form-control" type="hidden" name="galeria[]" value="/photos/1/300_21.jpg">
```

Hasta ahí funciona bien, pero si vuelvo a dar a `#galeria`, me crea otro ìnput cambiando la id y por el momento vacio:

```
 <input id="thumbnail32" class="form-control" type="hidden" name="galeria[]" value="/photos/1/300_21.jpg">

 <input id="thumbnail33" class="form-control" type="hidden" name="galeria[]"></a>
```

Al añadir una nueva foto, se me queda así:

```
<input id="thumbnail32" class="form-control" type="hidden" name="galeria[]" value="/photos/1/categorias/120.jpg">

<input id="thumbnail33" class="form-control" type="hidden" name="galeria[]"></a>
```

Si os fijais me cambia una url por la otra, y si no me equivoco la nueva url la tendria que haber puesto en el `thumbnail33`.

Comment: Podrías poner un link al paquete que estás utilizando? Y el código de Laravel.

Comment: Hola @azeós ya he puesto el link al paquete que estoy utilizando, que código de laravel necesitas ver??

Comment: Cuando decís que te _sobreescribe_ la imagen, quiero saber si eso es un problema de como estás guardando desde Laravel (ese es el código que quiero ver) o de como estás enviando la información. Por otro lado, no veo ningún elemento con la clase `lfm2`, que es la que estás usando para hacer el `.each()`. Podrías fijarte desde la solapa de red/network de tu explorador que se está enviando al hacer click en `#galeria`?

Comment: Hola @azeós lo de 'lfm2' fue fallo al copiar el código aquí, en mi código si que estaba.  Lo que hace al mirar el inspector de elemento es que crea lineas nuevas cada vez que le doy al botón `#galeria` pero las crea vacias, la foto siempre la pone en la misma linea y por eso la sustituye una por otra, voy a modificar la pregunta para mostrarte que pasa cuando hago click

Comment: Ya edite la pregunta para que este más clara @azeós

Comment: Hola @azeós a ver si me puedes ayudar que llevo bastante tiempo con esto, gracias!

Comment: Entiendo el problema pero me cuesta un poco darme cuenta que estás haciendo. Podrías editar tu pregunta y poner un ejemplo funcional? Cargá el código como un snippet y agregá la librería que estás utilizando; en fin, que se pueda proba el código desde acá. No entiendo que hace el `$('[class*="lfm2"]').each()`, tenés varios `.lfm2`?