# Rellenar select multiple (select2) dinamicamente Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

estoy haciendo la edición del producto.

Bien tengo una tabla que se llama `complementos`:
->Donde su columna identificativa es la columna `id`

Tengo una tabla intermedia que almacena que complementos tiene cada producto, se llama `producto_complementos`:
->Donde tiene una columna que se llama `producto_producto_id` que esta relacionada con la tabla productos y su `id`.
->Donde tiene otra columna que se llama `complemento_complemento_id` que esta relacionada con la `id` de la tabla complementos.

Entonces quiero que a la hora de hacer la edición del producto, me salga los complementos que tiene activos y además pueda seleccionar el resto, por si quiere el cliente añadir o quitar.

Lo estoy probando de la siguiente manera.

**El controlador**

```
public function editarProducto($id)
    { 
        $productos = Producto::findOrfail($id);
        $brands = Brand::get();
        $categorias = Categoria::get();
        $complementos = Producto_complemento::
            join('complementos', 'producto_complementos.complemento_complemento_id', '=', 'complementos.id')
            ->where('producto_complementos.producto_producto_id', $id)
            ->select('producto_complementos.*', 'complementos.name', 'complementos.id')
            ->get(); //Aquí intento sacar los complementos que tiene el producto y mostrar el nombre del complemento que esta en la tabla complementos
        $todosComplementos = Complemento::get(); //Aquí saco todos los complementos
                
        $subcategorias = Subcategoria::where('categoria', $productos->categoria)->get();
        return view("admin.edit_producto")->with(["productos" => $productos,
                                                  "brands" => $brands,
                                                  "categorias" => $categorias,
                                                  "subcategorias" => $subcategorias,
                                                  "complementos" => $complementos,
                                                  "todosComplementos" => $todosComplementos]);
    }
```

Luego intento rellenar el select del siguiente modo pero nada:

```
<select class="js-example-basic-multiple form-control formNuevo" name="complementos[]" multiple="multiple">
       @foreach ($todosComplementos as $todos)
           @if(empty($complementos))
             <option value=" {{ $todos->id }} " selected> {{ $todos->name }} </option>
           @else
             <option value=" {{ $todos->id }} "> {{ $todos->name }} </option>
           @endif  
       @endforeach
</select>
```

Probando así me toma el `else` y me muestra solo todos los complementos que están en la BD y no me muestra los ya seleccionados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no me equivoco, nunca recorres `$complementos`, por ende nunca vas a mostrar los seleccionados. Siempre recorres `$todosComplementos`.

Deberías hacer algo así

```
<select class="js-example-basic-multiple form-control formNuevo" name="complementos[]" multiple="multiple">
       @foreach ($complementos as $seleccionados)
           <option value=" {{ $seleccionados->id }} " selected> {{ $seleccionados->name }} </option> 
       @endforeach

       @foreach ($todosComplementos as $noSeleccionados)
           <option value=" {{ $noSeleccionados->id }} "> {{ $noSeleccionados->name }} </option> 
       @endforeach

</select>
```

En tu controlador deberías traer sólo los complementos que no han sido seleccionados, para que con los seleccionados se complementen y lo anterior funcione sin repeticiones. Algo así:

```
$complementosSeleccionados = Producto_complemento::
      where('producto_producto_id', $id)
      ->lists('complemento_complemento_id');

$todosComplementos = Complemento::whereNotIn('id', $complementosSeleccionados)->get();
```

Comment: Hola @L.Flor , me devuelve error el `whereNotIn` que puede ser?? `Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::whereNotIn(), 1 passed in`

Comment: Ya edité la respuesta, había olvidado la llave para comparar

Comment: Pero ahora las variables no son las mismas probe a cabiarlas pero me da error en la ID @L. Flor

Comment: Cambie `complemento_id` por `id` ya que en la tabla complementos es id. Pero me dice que `Trying to get property 'id' of non-object` , también cambie `list` por `pluck` ya que he leido que en laravel 5.8 ya no existe

Comment: Probablemente el array que retorna el query está vació, ya verificaste que retorne data haciendo un `dd($complementos)` o `dd($todosComplementos )`?

Comment: Pero tu linea `@foreach ($complementos as $seleccionados)` la cambie por `@foreach ($complementosSeleccionados as $seleccionados)`  eso es correcto? ya que la variable $complementos no existe @L. Flor

Comment: Además que la tabla de `Producto_complemento` solo trae la id del producto y la id del complemento, no hay nombre ni nada

Comment: No no, son dos consultas distintas, el query inicial que hiciste para `$complementos` te trae toda la data de los seleccionados. La siguiente query te trae sólo los `id` para hacer el filtro. No quise hacerlo todo en una sola consulta para no tocar lo que hiciste tú al inicio. Y el `foreach` debes dejarlo tal y como está en mi respuesta

Comment: Vale volvi a poner mi `join` y funciona perfectamente, pero no entiendo muy bien lo que hemos hecho

Comment: Por favor puedes mirar estas dos preguntas, llevan días sin solución: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/367514/rellena-inputs-con-javascritpt-sql-laravel y https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/366891/multiple-upload-laravel-file-manager gracias @L. Flor

Answer (score 0):

La logica correcta y simplificada sera la siguiente, apoyandonos de laravel blade y los metodos de laravel podemos hacerlo de esta manera, es un ejemplo funcional pero adaptalo a tus necesidades ya que de tu controlador se puede optimizar con relaciones de eloquent y hacer tus consultas mas rapidamente pero ese ya es otro tema

```
<select name="complementos[]" class="form-control select2"
                            multiple="multiple"
                            data-placeholder="Complementos"
                            style="width: 100%;">
                            @foreach ($complementos as $complemento)
                                <option {{ collect(old('complementos', $complementos->complementos->pluck('id')))->contains($complemento->id) ? 'selected' : '' }} value="{{ $complemento->id }}">{{ $complemento->name }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                            </select>
```

Comment: Y cual sera la query @Dohko19?

Comment: No se como tengas estrucuradas tu relaciones pero deberia bastar con ` $complementos = Producto_complemento::all();` y me arriesgo a equivocarme porque como ya dicho no se como tengas tus relaciones estructuradas